# Environment setting in a .net applilcation

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, environments

I need to know how we can control the environment setting in the application without manually changing the setting in app.config in my .net windows application.  In Java I would use a command line option (-D parameter) to set the environment when the app launches, example: java -D environment=1 myProgram.  Can I use .net SDKs msbuild here?
Please let me know if any of these solutions will be applicable in my case:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx

http://wallism.wordpress.com/2009/12/21/msbuild-and-multiple-environments/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/MSBuildForXml07282006005222AM/MSBuildForXml.aspx

[MSBuild Configuration Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137872/msbuild-configuration-files)

http://www.timvw.be/2008/03/17/easily-switching-between-appconfig-files-with-msbuild/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them in then System.Environment class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur comment.Cud u please tell me where do i put this code?It shud be invoked when the application launches.

Comment: Global asax in the application_start event

Comment: sorry, but this is a windows application.

Comment: the Program class, the Main() method

Comment: àh of my mistake :) what Alireza said the main method